# Iphone - Calling animations to a view from another class than the viewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Two really quick questions, I searched the web but couldn't find answers..

Is there any way to call block animations to a view from a class that is different from the viewController of that view. I also couldn't figure out how to add a subview to that view in a method that exists in a different class than the viewController ( the only way I can do it is [self.view addSubview:xxxxx]; in the viewController for my view)

Any help would be greatly appreciated and helpful.

Thank you!!

Comment: If you know how pointers work I believe you have a architectural problem.

Answer (score 1):

Keep a reference to YourViewController instance on ApplicationDelegate, and modify its subviews in OtherClass.

```
//in ApplicationDelegate.h
@property (strong, nonatomic) YourViewController *ref;

//in ApplicationDelegate.m
@synthesize ref;

self.ref = [[YourViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];



//in YourViewController.h
@property (retain, nonatomic) UIImageView *myImageView;

//in YourViewController.m
@synthesize myImageView;




//in OtherClass.m
[UIView animateWithDuration:DURATION delay:DELAY
                    options:OPTION
                 animations:^(void) 
        {
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate].ref.myImageView.center=CGPointMake(100,100);
        }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished)
        {
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate].ref.myImageView.center=CGPointMake(200,200);
        }];
```

Comment: It is indicative of poor code design to put a lot of application logic/UI in your AppDelegate. Your application delegate should only be used to initialize the bare minimum you need to begin sending messages from your view controllers. And yes, Apple does use it in their sample code, but only for the sake of simplicity for beginner developers.

Comment: So do I. He is a beginner developer I think.

Comment: By the way, I would like to remind: Don’t Abuse the App Delegate  http://www.hollance.com/category/beginners/

Comment: it turns out this is not hard at all as long as you have a pointer to that viewController. let's say that the view controller is called viewC, then you can call [viewC animateWithDuration:animations:] anywhere in that class which will work.

Comment: @erkanyildiz UR THE BESTTTTTTTTTT :))))))))) I have been struggling from days for this small piece of code. Tried all the ways and i was not having any hope when i was trying this and was my last attempt. anyways Thanks a Lot :))))) It just worked OUT :))))))))

Answer (score 0):

Well if the view that you're calling on the animation on also has a view controller then what you could do is create a method in that view controller that makes that animation. then in the other view that you want to call that animation you could do
    [otherViewController animationMethod]; 
Honestly that's the best i can think of.